# Why I can't connect from another client to the server?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Hi everybody I'm building a simple webapp using NodeJS+express4+socket.io at the last version available, basically the problem that I can't solve is that until I'm browsing to my webapp from a browser in the server it works perfectly, but when I'm trying to acces it from the same network but on another pc the index.html is served good but the client can't connect tonthe socket, here a piece of code:

**SERVER:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
var uptime;
var temp;
var sysOS;
var ramU;
var ramT;
var cpuUsage;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    console.log('Ok, Up and running on 8080');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var infos;
    var interval =setInterval(function(){
        //Get Uptime
        child = exec("uptime -p | grep 'up ' | cut -d ' ' -f2-", function(error, stdout, stderr){
            uptime = stdout;
        });
        //Get Temperature
        child = exec("/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | grep 'temp=' | cut -d '=' -f3,2-", function(error, stdout, stderr){
            temp = stdout;
        });
        //Get OS
        child = exec("cat /etc/os-release | grep 'PRETTY_NAME' | cut -d '=' -f2", function(error, stdout, stderr){
            sysOS = stdout;
        });
        //Get RAM USED
        child = exec("free -m | grep 'cache: ' | cut -d ' ' -f10", function(error, stdout, stderr){
            ramU = stdout;
        });
        //Get RAM TOTAL AVAILABLE
        child = exec("free -m | grep 'Mem: ' | cut -d ' ' -f12", function(error, stdout, stderr){
            ramT = stdout;
        });

        child = exec("top -bn 1 | awk 'NR>7{s+=$9} END {print s/4}' | tr -d ' '", function(error, stdout, stderr){
            cpuUsage = stdout;
        }); 
        infos = [{Uptime: uptime}, {Temperature: temp}, {OS: sysOS}, {ramUsed: ramU}, {ratTot: ramT}, {CPU: cpuUsage}];
        socket.emit("infos", infos);

    }, 2000);
});

console.log('Ok, Up and running on 8080');
server.listen(8080);
```

**CLIENT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var progressBar;
                var ramPerc;
                var cpu;
                var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080");
                socket.on("infos", function(infos) { 
                    cpu = infos[5].CPU.trim();
                    cpuPB = '<div class="progress"> <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:'+cpu+'%"> '+cpu+'% CPU USATA </div> </div>';
                    $("#uptempo").html(infos[0].Uptime);
                    $("#divTemp").html(infos[1].Temperature);
                    $("#divOS").html(infos[2].OS);
                    ramPerc = (((infos[3].ramUsed*100))/(infos[4].ratTot)).toFixed(2);
                    progressBar = "<div class='progress'> <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-success' role='progressbar' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:"+ ramPerc + "%'>"+ ramPerc + " % RAM usata </div> </div>";
                    $("#divRam").html(progressBar);
                    $("#divCpu").html(cpuPB);
                });
            });
```

In the client script of course I have to connect to http://localhost:8080/ so why from another client on the same network can't connect to it?
I'm I doing something wrong? Do I need to implement a proxy, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Localhost is an internal address only that references 127.0.0.1 , if you want to access your files from a different client in the same network you have to find your server's IP (run the following on terminal)

```
ipconfig getifaddr en0
```

and change the localhost reference for the server IP, i.e. http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080

You may also need to open the server firewall to external connections.